# Issue with routing (?) in site to site wireguard vpn in pfsense VM setup

Tags: networking, router, vpn, routing, wireguard

To preface, my networking experience is limited but I have a general sense of concepts and can definitely read up on any suggestions.

I am trying to set up a site-to-site with wireguard. Both sites use Asus routers since the setup and config are simple for the end user, but I have been tasked to connect the sites via VPN machines behind the routers that provide devices on Site A to access everything on Site B. The reason for the VPN on a separate machine behind the router is that the router CPUs are weak and transfer rates thru the VPN are too slow on the routers, so dedicated machines behind the router are being used as the VPN. I am looking to stick to free software options and cheap spare hardware, so ended up deciding on wireguard on pfsense on a dedicated ESXI machines.

Site A (home):

- Asus Router: 192.168.120.1/24 with static routing 192.168.110.0/24 to 192.168.120.55
- pfsense VM with wireguard: 192.168.120.55
- wireguard_A interface 10.0.8.1/24
- Peer Allowed IPs: 10.0.8.0/24, 192.168.110.0/24
- Gateway_to_B on wireguard_A: 10.0.8.2 with static routes 192.168.110.0/24

Site B (remote):

- Asus Router: 192.168.110.1/24 with routing 192.168.120.0/24 to 192.168.110.55
- pfsense VM with wireguard: 192.168.110.55
- wireguard_B interface 10.0.8.2/24
- Peer Allowed IPs: 10.0.8.0/24, 192.168.120.0/24
- Gateway_to_A on wireguard_B: 10.0.8.1 with static routes 192.168.120.0/24

What works:

- I can get a handshake for WG.
- from each pfsense GUI, I can ping the other site's wg interface and pfsense IP
- from pfsense on B, I can ping and traceroute A's router and devices

What doesn't work:

- from each pfsense GUI, I cannot trace route the other site's wg interface or pfsense IP (but I can ping them)
- from A's pfsense GUI, I cannot ping nor trace route to B's devices nor router-from devices on either network, I cannot ping the other site's network

Is my setup just totally off? Am I missing something? Any tips or pointers??

Thank you so much!

EDIT, adding additional request for information below (I trimmed some of the tunnel echo requests and replies):
tcpdump from pfsense A for a ping (ping successful):

```
95 IP 10.0.8.2 > 192.168.120.50: ICMP echo request, id 46148, seq 1, length 64
13:09:04.428941 IP 192.168.120.50 > 10.0.8.2: ICMP echo reply, id 46148, seq 1, length 64
13:09:04.538993 IP 10.0.8.2 > 10.0.8.1: ICMP echo request, id 38069, seq 18882, length 9
13:09:04.839346 IP 10.0.8.2 > 10.0.8.1: ICMP echo reply, id 10026, seq 42123, length 9
13:09:05.448670 IP 10.0.8.2 > 192.168.120.50: ICMP echo request, id 46148, seq 2, length 64
13:09:05.448840 IP 192.168.120.50 > 10.0.8.2: ICMP echo reply, id 46148, seq 2, length 64
13:09:05.598724 IP 10.0.8.2 > 10.0.8.1: ICMP echo request, id 38069, seq 18884, length 9
```

tcpdump below from pfsense A, traceroute (trace stops at 10.0.8.1):

```
13:14:13.054009 IP 10.0.8.2 > 10.0.8.1: ICMP echo reply, id 10026, seq 42698, length 9
13:14:13.313649 IP 10.0.8.2.61530 > 192.168.120.50.33435: UDP, length 12
13:14:13.313689 IP 10.0.8.1 > 10.0.8.2: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 48
13:14:13.383640 IP 10.0.8.2.61530 > 192.168.120.50.33436: UDP, length 12
13:14:13.383679 IP 10.0.8.1 > 10.0.8.2: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 48
13:14:13.443543 IP 10.0.8.2.61530 > 192.168.120.50.33437: UDP, length 12
13:14:13.443569 IP 10.0.8.1 > 10.0.8.2: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 48
13:14:13.508499 IP 10.0.8.2 > 10.0.8.1: ICMP echo request, id 38069, seq 19460, length 9
13:14:13.508514 IP 10.0.8.1 > 10.0.8.2: ICMP echo reply, id 38069, seq 19460, length 9
13:14:13.508543 IP 10.0.8.2.61530 > 192.168.120.50.33438: UDP, length 12
13:14:13.518462 IP 10.0.8.1 > 10.0.8.2: ICMP echo request, id 10026, seq 42699, length 9
13:14:13.584084 IP 10.0.8.2 > 10.0.8.1: ICMP echo reply, id 10026, seq 42699, length 9
13:14:13.908636 IP 10.0.8.2.40151 > 192.168.120.50.33443: UDP, length 12
13:14:14.044168 IP 10.0.8.1 > 10.0.8.2: ICMP echo request, id 10026, seq 42700, length 9
13:14:14.044175 IP 10.0.8.2 > 10.0.8.1: ICMP echo request, id 38069, seq 19461, length 9
13:14:14.044187 IP 10.0.8.1 > 10.0.8.2: ICMP echo reply, id 38069, seq 19461, length 9
13:14:14.113502 IP 10.0.8.2 > 10.0.8.1: ICMP echo reply, id 10026, seq 42700, length 9
13:14:15.188567 IP 10.0.8.2 > 10.0.8.1: ICMP echo reply, id 10026, seq 42702, length 9
13:14:15.533688 IP 10.0.8.2.61530 > 192.168.120.50.33439: UDP, length 12
13:14:15.663551 IP 10.0.8.2 > 10.0.8.1: ICMP echo request, id 38069, seq 19464, length 9
13:14:15.663562 IP 10.0.8.1 > 10.0.8.2: ICMP echo request, id 10026, seq 42703, length 9
13:14:15.663573 IP 10.0.8.1 > 10.0.8.2: ICMP echo reply, id 38069, seq 19464, length 9
13:14:15.728480 IP 10.0.8.2 > 10.0.8.1: ICMP echo reply, id 10026, seq 42703, length 9
13:14:15.934292 IP 10.0.8.2.40151 > 192.168.120.50.33444: UDP, length 12
13:14:16.183603 IP 10.0.8.1 > 10.0.8.2: ICMP echo request, id 10026, seq 42704, length 9
```

tcpdump from pfsense B for a ping (ping unsuccessful):

```
13:17:56.866941 IP 10.0.8.1 > 192.168.110.81: ICMP echo request, id 35076, seq 0, length 64
13:17:56.903449 IP 10.0.8.1 > 10.0.8.2: ICMP echo reply, id 38069, seq 19878, length 9
13:17:57.867472 IP 10.0.8.1 > 192.168.110.81: ICMP echo request, id 35076, seq 1, length 64
13:17:57.887689 IP 10.0.8.1 > 10.0.8.2: ICMP echo request, id 10026, seq 43118, length 9
13:17:57.887709 IP 10.0.8.2 > 10.0.8.1: ICMP echo reply, id 10026, seq 43118, length 9
13:17:57.887717 IP 10.0.8.2 > 10.0.8.1: ICMP echo request, id 38069, seq 19880, length 9
13:17:57.948202 IP 10.0.8.1 > 10.0.8.2: ICMP echo reply, id 38069, seq 19880, length 9
13:17:58.901775 IP 10.0.8.1 > 192.168.110.81: ICMP echo request, id 35076, seq 2, length 64
13:17:58.970017 IP 10.0.8.2 > 10.0.8.1: ICMP echo request, id 38069, seq 19882, length 9
13:17:58.971989 IP 10.0.8.1 > 10.0.8.2: ICMP echo request, id 10026, seq 43120, length 9
```

tcpdump from pfsense A, traceroute (trace stops at 10.0.8.2):

```
13:18:58.412887 IP 10.0.8.1.61640 > 192.168.110.81.33435: UDP, length 12
13:18:58.412921 IP 10.0.8.2 > 10.0.8.1: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 48
13:18:58.454527 IP 10.0.8.2 > 10.0.8.1: ICMP echo request, id 38069, seq 19993, length 9
13:18:58.471872 IP 10.0.8.1 > 10.0.8.2: ICMP echo request, id 10026, seq 43231, length 9
13:18:58.471891 IP 10.0.8.2 > 10.0.8.1: ICMP echo reply, id 10026, seq 43231, length 9
13:18:58.472828 IP 10.0.8.1.61640 > 192.168.110.81.33436: UDP, length 12
13:18:58.472867 IP 10.0.8.2 > 10.0.8.1: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 48
13:18:58.517860 IP 10.0.8.1 > 10.0.8.2: ICMP echo reply, id 38069, seq 19993, length 9
13:18:58.533516 IP 10.0.8.1.61640 > 192.168.110.81.33437: UDP, length 12
13:18:58.533556 IP 10.0.8.2 > 10.0.8.1: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 48
13:18:58.604429 IP 10.0.8.1.61640 > 192.168.110.81.33438: UDP, length 12
13:18:58.995806 IP 10.0.8.2 > 10.0.8.1: ICMP echo request, id 38069, seq 19994, length 9
13:19:00.608650 IP 10.0.8.2 > 10.0.8.1: ICMP echo reply, id 10026, seq 43235, length 9
13:19:00.609243 IP 10.0.8.1.61640 > 192.168.110.81.33439: UDP, leng
```

Comment: Do your pfSense firewall rules allow all packet types from the WG interfaces? (traceroute on Linux & BSD defaults to using UDP probes instead of ICMP pings, so if it doesn't work while ping does, that's often a firewall thing.) Can you ssh into the pfSense gateways and `tcpdump -n -i wg0` to see whether the traceroute and ping packets go out through one end (and whether the same packets arrive in through the other)?

Comment: @user1686 Appreciate the reply! Yes, I added an allow-all on the WG interfaces on the pfsense firewall. I did the tcpdump and edited the original post with that information. Let me know if I need to include more of the dump. Thanks again!